# Convertir una lista a lista parameters

Tags: c#, api, lista, get, parametros

En cada case hacer la consulta a cada maestro y convertir esa lista a la lista parameters

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor reformula la pregunta. No se entiende cuál es.

Comment: Agrega el código como texto por favor ,  revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta